# The Arrows of Fate

Tags: churban-destruction, tisha-bav, maseches-gitin

When Nero landed in Israel, he shoot arrows in all directions.

What was the significance of this action?

Comment: Where is this Gemara that you cite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Ben Yehoydah** says the reason he shot arrows was to teach us a lesson regarding the reason of the destruction of the *Beis Hamikdash*. The Beis Hamikdash was destroyed because of the sin of *Lashon Hara*. That is, just as a sword can not destroy something from afar but an arrow can, so too *Loshon Hara* destroys people from afar. The reason Nero shot arrows in four directions was, (in addition to the first which was simply an indicator) was because this is similar to Loshon Hara which destroys three people - the person who hears it, the person who said it, and the person who was spoken about.